# Symmetric sparse matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I have the impedance matrix [Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SypN.png), formulated from an electrical network by augmented nodal analysis. The matrix [Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SypN.png) is shown as an image to illustrate its feature visually, where all the white blocks are zero.  What could be the best possible way to inverse such matrix which is required to solve the linear equation in the form **[Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SypN.png)x=b**? Furthermore, in each iteration of the network solution, only the first 8x8 elements get new values. All other elements remain as is. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In such a scenario, you wouldn't calculate the complete matrix inverse, but use an iterative method to solve the linear equation for the particular given right hand side $b$. As the impedance matrix is symmetric positive definite (as far as I can remember), you could use the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

Comment: First of all, many thanks for helping me out of this problem. 
Unfortunately, in this case, the matrix Y is not a positive definite matrix, as not all their eigenvalues are positive. In that case, is it possible to use [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method)